# Numba ahead-of-time (AOT) compiling with dependent functions

Tags: python, numba

I have a function that calls another function, and I would like to use numba's ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler.

Simplified example:

```
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('test')
cc.verbose = True


@cc.export('calc', 'f8(f8, f8)')
def calc(a, b):
    return a + b


@cc.export('calc2', 'f8(f8, f8)')
def calc2(a, b):
    return a * calc(a, b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Untyped global name 'calc': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

I assume that this means Numba doesn't like dependent functions.
Suggestions on how get around this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `@njit()` decorator in front of the dependent function.
For the case at hand, the code would become:

```
@nb.njit()
@cc.export('calc', 'f8(f8, f8)')
def calc(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly oversight!